# Xcode 7.3, Share Extension, Can't seem to pass data from extension to container app

Tags: swift, share-extension

Xcode 7.3, iPhone 6s+ ios 9.2.1

All seems to be setup ok with the group share for the container and the share extension.  The extension methods get called correctly.  But no matter what is tried (shared user defaults) or (shared file access) the code to set the user default or write the file just seems to "break out" of scope.

Some examples of the code

```
      if let defaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.propergroupname") {
          defaults.setObject(url, forKey: "url")
          defaults.setObject("", forKey: "post")
          defaults.synchronize()
```

let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

```
    if let directory = fileManager.containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier("group.propergroupname") {
        let stringUrl = self.selectedMovie!.URL.absoluteString
        let filename = directory.absoluteString + "videodata.txt"
        do {
            try
                stringUrl.writeToFile(filename, atomically: true, encoding:  NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            print("file written")
        } catch {
            print("file write problem")
        }
    }
```

So for the defaults, the first defaults.setObject just breaks out.

For the file, the writeToFile breaks out.

So how to get information from the Share Extension to the Container App?

Answer (score 0):

Did you switch on App Groups? (Check attached screenshot).

Also check that you are using "group.propergroupname" as your app group name.

[image]

Comment: Yep for both the container app and the share extension.

Comment: http://imgur.com/sip7C2B If you are seeing all ticks, then maybe you can 1. Clean Build folder, delete Derived Data folder and restart Xcode. 2. Check on developer portal if your old provisioning profile has invalidated and you are still using it.

Comment: Been there done that.  Have been doing iOS quite a bit.  Like I said, have tried all of the tricks and still no go.

Comment: Then I will suggest you to try and do this in a test project. Just to confirm we are not missing any major step.